# How to detect drag events from outside the app in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11

I've working with the new Apple API to enable drop interactions on a custom view.
The thing is that the drag source is from outside the app (Safari/Photos/Files).
Does anyone know a way to detect when the drag operation start so then I can put a something like  a "drop here" view 
in my custom view?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to add a `UIDropInteraction` to whatever view you're trying to drop content on.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {            
    let dropInteraction = UIDropInteraction.init(delegate: self)

    //The target view could be anything, a UILabel, UIImageView, UIView as long as it is a descendant of UIView
    dropTargetView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //Very important
    dropTargetView.addInteraction(dropInteraction)

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

The delegate method, `canHandleSession` of `UIDropInteractionDelegate` queries if you can handle the current drop session:

```
extension ViewController: UIDropInteractionDelegate {
    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: ["kUTTypeImage"]) && session.items.count == 1
    }
}
```

**You can pretty much show your "Drop items here" image in this situation if the method returns true.**

> You can't check the actual data the user is dragging because it isn’t available when the interaction calls this method. Only the data type is available inside this method (`canHandleSession`).

If you want to have control during the course of user dragging the content inside your drop area, `sessionDidUpdate` delegate method should be used. **Here you will be able to know drag events from outside of your app (Answer to your question).**

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
        
        let dropLocation = session.location(in: self.view)
        let dropOperation: UIDropOperation
        
        //Here you will know if the drag that user performs is inside your expected area, so you can show your "Drop here" graphic here.
        if self.view.frame.contains(dropLocation) {
            //If you happen to drag and drop from a different app, localDragSession will be nil
            dropOperation = session.localDragSession == nil ? .copy : .cancel 
        } else {
            dropOperation = .cancel
        }
        
        return UIDropProposal.init(operation: dropOperation)
    }
```

And finally to execute the drop, implement `performDrop` method.